# JSON Can't alert object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, web-services

I have the below JSON object. In Javascript i want to alert for the username. the below is not working.

```
alert(jsonobject[0].User_Name);
```

[{"User_ID":"4","User_Name":"steve","User_Password":"","User_Role_ID":"1","User_Active":"1"}]

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problem faced?

Comment: [your code](https://jsfiddle.net/nhx8k43z/) works fine

Comment: I am getting this error "Cannot read property 'User_Name' of undefined"

Comment: how do you get from `[{"User_ID":"4","User_Name":"steve","User_Password":"","User_Role_ID":"1","User_Active":"1"}]` to a javascript variable named `jsonobject`? (P.S. there is no such thing as a JSON object ... JSON is purely a string ... you must JSON.parse it, to get a **javascript** object

Comment: here is the full controller code.
scotchApp.controller('modifyuserController', function($scope, $http,dataFactory){
  datatosend = dataFactory.getval();
  $http.get('http://192.168.50.55/phpscripts/getuserdata.php?userid=' + datatosend).
   then(function (responseText) {
    inputdata = responseText;
    alert(inputdata[0].User_Name);

Comment: how about adding the code to the question, where it is readable - and then, in then, add a `console.log(inputdata)` - see what you get. Is it a string? an array? something else?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var json = '[{"User_ID":"4","User_Name":"steve","User_Password":"","User_Role_ID":"1","User_Active":"1"}]';

var obj = JSON.parse(json);

alert(obj[0].User_Name)
```

Comment: In the question, he simply states that it's not working. In a comment, after (or during my post) he stated that jsonobject[0] is not defined which means it's not a javascript object. I stand by my answer. Either it wasn't converted or the JSON is malformed in whatever source he is getting it from.

Comment: Either way hope this helps get you on the right track.

Comment: you guys all rock!!! IDK why but i had to obj.data[0].User_Name. it was the idea to look at the console that got me to see the data i'm getting back is more then just a json object.